# Making SVG inline sprites fluid

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design, sprite

I have a nice inline svg sprite system that I am using, but it would really be nice to give these percentage dimensions so that they scale based on the container size. Here is one sprite:

```
<svg class="svg"><use xlink:href="images/sprites/svgsprite.svg#no-1"></use></svg>
```

When I apply the following css:

```
.svg {
    width: 20%;
}
```

This, however, just gives the svg container a width of 20%, but the  element is at a fixed width inside the svg container. Even after applying a width of 100% to the  element, the style won't get applied. I was wondering is there a way to make these sprites responsive? After researching, I can't find many people attempting to make svg sprites responsive, but I don't understand why since they cut down on http requests.

Comment: The viewBox attribute does that.

Comment: Interestingly the viewBox attribute is set differently to the rendered size (180px by 175px) vs (155px by 150px)